# Dart TreeSanitzer: No static getter 'trusted' declared in class 'NodeTreeSanitizer'

Tags: calendar, dart, bootjack

I'm using the Bootjack Datepicker and after upgrading Dart to 1.12.1, I'm all of a sudden seeing only half a calendar with no days and with this exception:

> Exception: No static getter 'trusted' declared in class
>   'NodeTreeSanitizer'. NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'trusted'
>   Receiver: Type: class 'NodeTreeSanitizer'

This is the only line of code needed to wire the calendar:

```
Calendar.use();
```

If you need to manually wire the calendar, you can manually call:

```
Calendar.wire(querySelector("div.calendar"));
```

Both of them are giving me the exception in `calendar.dart`

The code that seems to be breaking is:

```
void _dayView() {
    TableElement calBody = element.querySelector('.cnt');
    Element dow = calBody.tBodies[0].createFragment(_DOW_TEMPLATE).children[0];
    List<Element> children = dow.children;

    List<String> swkDays = _dfmt.dateSymbols.SHORTWEEKDAYS;
    int ofs = (_firstDayOfWeek + 1) % 7;
    //render week days
    for (int i = swkDays.length; --i >= 0;) {
      children[i].text = swkDays[(i + ofs) % 7];
    }

    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 6; --i >= 0;) {
      buffer.write(_DAYROW_TEMPLATE);
    }

    calBody.tBodies[0]
    ..append(dow)
    ..appendHtml(buffer.toString(), treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);   <<<<<<<< ERROR
  }
```

Looking at appendHtml, I can see `treeSanitizer` is an optional param, so that syntax looks fine. In the abstract class `NodeTreeSanitizer`, I can see: `static const trusted = const _TrustedHtmlTreeSanitizer();`, so that seems to be fine as well.

Any idea what could be causing this error?

I've logged a bug here in the meantime: https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack-datepicker/issues/2

Comment: `NodeTreeSaniztizer.trusted` was added only recently. Where do you get this error? In Dartium or Chrome or both? What Dart version are you using?

Comment: I'm seeing this in Dartium, in compiled JS on production, the calendar seems to work. `pub --version` outputs 1.12.1. Are you suggesting that my Dartium might be outdated?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your Dartium is outdated. You could check the Dart version in `about://version` in Dartium.

Comment: Dart version says 1.11.1, so that's probably why it's  breaking since I'm on 1.12.1. I've already done a brew update and brew upgrade and there seems to be no updates to Dartium. Will try and re-install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Dartium version is outdated.
Please compare the output of `dart --version` (command line) and the Dart version on the `about://version` page in Dartium.

Comment: How do I upgrade Dartium? Looking in `/usr/local/Cellar/dartium`, I can see several dozen versions of Dartium stopping at 1.11.1. `brew update & brew upgrade dartium` returns `Error: No available formula for dart-lang/dart/dartium`. Has dartium been removed from Homebrew?

Comment: I'm on Linux, don't know about `brew`. Have you tried uninstalling and install with `brew install dart --with-dartium`, `brew linkapps` (https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart). Update is done with `brew update`,`brew upgrade dart`. If it doesn't work please file an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/issues

Comment: Yes, just removed dart completely from my system and reinstalling with the special flags. I can see Dartium 1.12.1 downloading now. In the past, it used to be two separate packages, it seems they've been merged into one package now and the --with-dartium option wasn't available back then, so I never had that flag ticked. Thanks for the help!